# .Need to check whether the facebook user is atleast 3 months on facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just want to check whether the facebook user is atleast on facebook for more than 3 months. This is being used by an Facebook Application.

I have all permissions with me.

I am using Facebook C# SDK and using facebook graph API.

Doesnt matter if it is even 60% accurate

I googled it for too long but doesnt find anything

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You realize that Facebook users have to be 13 and older I assume: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210644045634222

Comment: @peterept I want to ask how long the user is on facebook and not his/her age.

Comment: @peterept i have updated the question too

Comment: a dirty hack will be to fetch posts before 3 months and see if you get a hit :)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, using this query it's not totally what you are looking for but:

```
fql?q=SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() AND created_time < 1327677300 LIMIT 1
```

If this query returns something then you are sure the user is on facebook from more than 3 months. Otherwise if the query returns an empty array *probably* the user is not at least 3 months on facebook, but you cannot be totally sure of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is always hard to answer this with certainity but there is no information on how to retrieve this field in any permission or data received from Facebook. I have never come across it.

From this lack of information I would say it is not possible.

A possible solution, would be to get access to the user post's and get the date of the earliest one.